# Code not running in IE 11, works fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, startswith

The following code can be run without a problem in Chrome, but throws the following error in Internet Explorer 11.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'

I am storing the element's ID in a variable. What is the issue?

```js
function changeClass(elId) {
  var array = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  
  for (var a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
    var str = array[a].id;
    
    if (str.startsWith('REP')) {
      if (str == elId) {
        array[a].style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
        array[a].style.color = "white";
      } else {
        array[a].style.backgroundColor = "";
        array[a].style.color = "";
      }
    } else if (str.startsWith('D')) {
      if (str == elId) {
        array[a].style.backgroundColor = "Blue";
        array[a].style.color = "white";
      } else {
        array[a].style.backgroundColor = "";
        array[a].style.color = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="REP1" onclick="changeClass('REP1');">REPS</td>
    <td id="td1">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="D1" onclick="changeClass('D1');">Doors</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="D12" onclick="changeClass('D12');">Doors</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You'll likely need to use `str.indexOf("REP") == 0` for IE instead.

Comment: ES6 is not yet a standard https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ There is an ES6 shim library to help the transition https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/ Just like for ES5 (including not everything is shimmable)

Answer (score 334, accepted):

[`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is a standard method in the most recent version of JavaScript, ES6.

Looking at the compatibility table below, we can see that it is supported on all current major platforms, *except* versions of Internet Explorer.

```
╔═══════════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╦═══════════════════╦═══════╦════════╗
║    Feature    ║ Chrome ║ Firefox ║ Edge  ║ Internet Explorer ║ Opera ║ Safari ║
╠═══════════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╬════════╣
║ Basic Support ║    41+ ║     17+ ║ (Yes) ║ No Support        ║    28 ║      9 ║
╚═══════════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╩═══════════════════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

You'll need to implement `.startsWith` yourself. Here is the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill):

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

Comment: there are another implementation at [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill) `String.prototype.startsWith = function(search, pos) {
         return this.substr(!pos || pos < 0 ? 0 : +pos, search.length) === search;
    };`

Comment: I tend to the first implementation as given by @Oka. Just as an additional refinement one might test for "position" being really numeric:
position = !isNaN(parseInt(position)) ? position : 0;

Answer (score 40):

`text.indexOf("newString")` is the best method instead of `startsWith`.

Example:

```
var text = "Format";
if(text.indexOf("Format") == 0) {
    alert(text + " = Format");
} else {
    alert(text + " != Format");
}
```

Comment: Why is it the best method?

Comment: indexOf Method in not replacement for startsWith, indexOf will return value if it matches any where in given string, i don't suggest to use indexOf.

Comment: `indexOf` does return value, but @Jona has checked that the return value is zero (i.e. the string is at the beginning), meaning it *is* a good replacement for `startsWith`!

Comment: This is the same functionality as the polyfill without having to add a polyfill or bring in an extra library. It's an excellent solution - the only downside I can see is perhaps code readability- the intention is more clear when the function is named startsWith.

Answer (score 14):

If this is happening in Angular 2+ application, you can just **uncomment** string polyfills in **polyfills.ts**:

```
import 'core-js/es6/string';
```

Comment: I added the Oka's polyfill fix, but it didn't work for me on my Angular 5 application, but `import 'core-js/es6/string';` fixed it. Many thanks!

Comment: It appears that the polyfill has moved to `import 'core-js/es/string';`. I'm on Angular 10. `import 'core-js/stable/string/starts-with';` seems even better though

Answer (score 7):

**Replace the startsWith function with:**

```
yourString.indexOf(searchString, position) // where position can be set to 0
```

This will support all browsers including IE

**Position can be set to 0 for string matching from the start meaning 0th position.**

Comment: Useful solution without having to rewrite prototypes nor using polyfills. Plus it is wide compatible among browsers. +1

Answer (score 2):

As others have said startsWith and endsWith are part of ES6 and not available in IE11. Our company always uses lodash library as a polyfill solution for IE11. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

```
_.startsWith([string=''], [target], [position=0])
```

Answer (score 0):

While the post of Oka is working great, it might be a bit outdated. I figured out that [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#startsWith) can tackle it with one single function. If you have lodash installed, it might save you a few lines.

Just try:

```
import { startsWith } from lodash;
```

.
.
.

```
    if (startsWith(yourVariable, 'REP')) {
         return yourVariable;        
    return yourVariable;
       }      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recently faced the prob. I solved using ^ which is similar to startwith in 
`jquery`. Say,

```
var str = array[a].id;
if (str.startsWith('REP')) {..........}
```

we can use

```
if($("[id^=str]").length){..........}
```

Here, str is id of element.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this method if problem comes when working with angular2+ projects**

I was looking for a solution when i got this error, and it got me here. But this question seems to be specific but the error is not, its a generic error. This is a common error for angular developers dealing with Internet Explorer.

> I had the same issue while working with angular 2+, and it got resolved just by few simple steps.

In Angular latest versions, there are come commented codes in the **polyfills.ts**  shows all the polyfills required  for the smooth running in Internet Explorer versions IE09,IE10 and IE11

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
//import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
//import 'core-js/es6/object';
//import 'core-js/es6/function';
//import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
//import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
//import 'core-js/es6/number';
//import 'core-js/es6/math';
//import 'core-js/es6/string';
//import 'core-js/es6/date';
//import 'core-js/es6/array';
//import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
//import 'core-js/es6/map';
//import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
//import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

**Uncomment the codes and it would work perfectly in IE browsers**

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

But you might see a performance drop in IE browsers compared to others :(