# How to solve TypeError for app on IE11 - AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer

I have an Angular5 single-page app that works perfectly on Google Chrome, Firefox, Microsoft Edge and mobile browsers. However, with IE11, I get the errors:

`ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'find'`

and

`ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'startswith'`

Based on Angular docs, it's supposed to support IE11. I tried to apply fixes on the browser settings (as per Microsoft forums) like `reset` Advanced Settings in Internet Options and trying in compatibility mode, etc. But nothing on the browser configuration worked.

Is there any special configuration required on Angular side to make it work on IE11? How can I fix the errors mentioned above?

I'm not sure which code samples may be relevant, please let me know and I can provide. Thanks.

EDIT: More details on the accepted solution can be found in [Angular - Browser Support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support). Specifically, enabling polyfills.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code not running in IE 11, works fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867172/code-not-running-in-ie-11-works-fine-in-chrome)

Comment: Be sure to upvote the [angular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43993689/2033671)

Comment: @ProfessorAllman Answer to that question, while correct, wasn't exactly the solution for me. There was an Angular specific solution rather than doing it manually as the answer there suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a file called

> polyfills.ts

In it, you can uncomment various polyfills for different browsers. Just read the commentblocks.

Comment: After trichtriche's answer, I actually found this as well. I simply needed to uncomment some of the imports and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Those errors pop because IE doesn't implement those functions.

To resolve this, simply look for the functions on MDN's website.

For instance, **[here is the find method](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/find)**.

If you go to the bottom of the page, you will find a **polyfill** for this function (in the page I gave you, in french, it is `Prothèse d'émulation`).

Simply copy and paste your code into a Typescript file, and import that typescript file into your project.