# internet explorer not able to type anything in input type=text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am testing my react app in IE-10 and not able to type in my input text-box. It works fine in other browsers. I had no idea about it. Can anyone help me out on this.

getting:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith' error on typing

Comment: Show code or didn't happen

Comment: There could be hundreds of potential reasons why IE is misbehaving. It's basically what IE does best. You need to provide with more details like some code and/or some console output to help us help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code not running in IE 11, works fine in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867172/code-not-running-in-ie-11-works-fine-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by importing 'core-js/es6/string' in main.js file

Comment: You might find https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility useful. In this particular case, this is specifically for `startsWith` but if you experience similar issues you should check the compatibility table of functions.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occur due to corrupt Internet explorer settings.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie10-windows_7/cant-type-text-in-ie10/47633107-5309-4848-a987-de2bb7010d69
(Also holds good for Internet explorer 11)

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Linking the original external source is great. But an answer has be self contained, and provide a solution without the need to navigate to an external site. The problem with external links is that they might not be valid anymore in future which would make your answer useless.